# Ran 0 tests in 0.000s. Flask

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am pretty unsure why this is happening? I tried all the recommendations online but still not working. Any ideas?

I checked my indentation
I checked the file name "test_*.py"
I checked the imports
I checked the function names (all start with test_)

But nothing is working, any ideas?

Edit: when I run my file directly using python test_file.py it works fine?

```
from glare_RESTAPI import app 
import unittest
from flask import jsonify
app.testing = True

class FlaskTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    #Test for 201 response from POST method
    def test_index(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        input = jsonify({
            'lat': 49.2699648,
            'lon': -123.1290368, 
            'epoch': 1588704959.321,
            'orientation': -10
            })
        result = tester.post("/detect_glare", input)
        statuscode = result.status_code
        self.assertEqual(statuscode, 201)

    #Test for json data result
    def test_index_content(self):
        tester = app.test_client(self)
        input = jsonify({
            'lat': 49.2699648,
            'lon': -123.1290368, 
            'epoch': 1588704959.321,
            'orientation': -10
            })
        result = tester.post("/detect_glare", input)
        self.assertEqual(result.content_type, "application/json")




if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Comment: You didn't say how you run your tests.

Comment: just using Python -m unittest

Comment: Hm, thats strange -  `python -m unittest` doesn't find the test, obviously. Do you run this at the path where the test file is located?